# How can I change the folder location for QGIS temporary files?

Tags: qgis, windows, configuration

Even though I specify specific files for output, there are still a lot of temporary data being written to C:\Users\me\AppData\etc

My C drive is a very limited capacity SSD and it's driving me nuts that I can't tell where QGIS to go for ALL temporary data.

Maybe there's a configuration file (python, etc) that I can change this value assuming there's no dialog box in the UI to do that?  Has anyone successfully changed this?

I already changed the option in Processing->Options but that's the "default" directory for writing out files, not for temporary data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In **Settings -> Options -> System** of QGIS, you will be able to see the read only current environment variables of your system; precisely the folder where your temporary data are being written (see next image).

[image]

You can edit the path of these folders by using the Control Panel of Windows (filtering by **env** at the browser); see next image.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Some QGIS installers have this option in advanced section to install this Local Package Directory; as it can be observed in following [image](https://gyazo.com/6461f730c1e1b34c6488424369f84e42):

[image]

Comment: This answer is not related to the question.