# Relocate the temporary files directory in QGIS due to the limited capacity of C drive

Tags: qgis, windows, storage

My C drive has limited storage space, and QGIS is currently using it for all temporary files during processing. I believe I need to change the file path location. How can I do this, or are there other options available?

Comment: Not quite sure if I understood you correctly - but temporary files like outputs of an algorithm are stored just in memory, not written to the disk. Only when you define a path before running will they be written to the disk.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156129/how-can-i-change-the-folder-location-for-qgis-temporary-files